# Help in evaluating an integral over $D$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a flat area $D$ enclosed between $xy=1,xy=0$ and $y=x,y=4x$ in $xy-$ plane when $x,y\geq 0$. If $f=\sqrt{y/x}+\sqrt{xy}$, how can I find $$\iint_D fdA$$ Thank you for hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Just some points. The area $D$ is as follows: $$D:~~0\leq x,~0\leq y,~1\leq xy\leq 9,~x\leq y\leq 4x$$ or $$D:~~0\leq x,~0\leq y,~1\leq xy\leq 9,~1\leq\frac{y}{x}\leq 4$$ Now take $u=xy,~~v=\frac{y}{x}$ and the converted area $$D':~1\leq u\leq 9,~1\leq v\leq 4 $$ accordingly and then find the integral $$\iint_{D'}(\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{v})\frac{1}{2v}dudv$$ instead. Do you know what $\frac{1}{2v}$ is above?